# Pure HTML input type date - set min date to 1.1.1970

Tags: html

how do I set a min date to `<input type="date">` in HTML? I tried using the `min` attribute but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you do it? It should work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#htmlattrdefmin

Comment: in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format but it doesn't work

Comment: nvm I'm just stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the `min` attribute.
It should work fine in most browsers.

```html
<input type="date" min="1970-01-01" />
```

I know you asked for pure HTML but if it doesn't work for you, you can achieve the same result with this:

`document.getElementById("myDatePicker").min = "1970-01-01";`